# Adding <mark> tags based on user search by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am working on a functionality that highlights text in a list of items using the `<mark>` tag based on user input. I cannot simplify the HTML code of the `<li>` tags. I have a version that works for simple cases. For example, when searching for `Ba` the result looks like this:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hide-balise" id="hide-balise">
  <label for="hide-balise"><mark>Ba</mark>lise</label>
</li>
```

However, I am facing challenges in making this form case-insensitive. If a user searches for `css` in lowercase, I want the `<mark>` tags to be added like this:`<mark>CSS</mark>`, while preserving the original uppercase letters from the HTML code. Additionally, the search does not work when the searched portion is at the end or in the middle. For instance, searching for `Sheet` does not result in the addition of the `<mark>` tag.

These issues seem also related to the regex. Can you assist me in improving it to handle these different scenarios in the search?

I have already reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-tags-from-text-using-plain-javascript).

Below is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function addMarks(event) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`>[a-zA-Z]*${event.currentTarget.value}[a-zA-Z]*<`, 'gi');
  for (const li of items) {
    li.innerHTML.match(regex)?.forEach((match) => {
      li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replace(
        match,
        match.replaceAll(event.currentTarget.value, `<mark>${event.currentTarget.value}</mark>`),
      );
    });
  }
}

function clearMarks() {
  items.forEach((li) => {
    li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replaceAll('<mark>', '');
    li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replaceAll('</mark>', '');
  });
}

document.querySelector('input[type=text]').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  clearMarks();
  if (event.currentTarget.value.trim() !== '') {
    addMarks(event);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search">
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-balise" id="hide-balise">
    <label for="hide-balise">Balise</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-div" id="hide-div">
    <label for="hide-div">
      <abbr lang="en" title="division">div</abbr>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-div" id="hide-div-with-entities">
    <label for="hide-div-with-entities">
      <abbr lang="en" title="division">&lt;div&gt;</abbr>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-attribut" id="hide-attribut">
    <label for="hide-attribut">Attribut</label></li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-css" id="hide-css">
    <label for="hide-css">
      <abbr lang="en" title="Cascading Style Sheets">mark</abbr>
      (<i lang="en">Cascading Style Sheets</i>)
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-attribut" id="hide-ancre">
    <label for="hide-ancre">Ancre (<i lang="en">Anchor</i>)</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `>[a-zA-Z]*${event.currentTarget.value}[a-zA-Z]*<` - your expression demands that between the tag closing `>` and opening `<`, your search term must be surrounded by nothing but letters. For the `Sheets` in your example HTML, that is clearly not the case.

Comment: As for case-sensitive - you are currently replacing with the search term, as the user entered it. What you should do instead, is have your regular expression _capture_ the found match, and use that as the replacement.

Comment: You can remove `li.innerHTML.match(regex)?.forEach((match) => {` and then just use ``li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(`(>[^<>]*)(${event.currentTarget.value})([^<>]*<)`, 'gi'), '$1<mark>$2</mark>$3')``

Answer (score -2):

There is one issue with your regular expression in the addMarks function. Additionally, I recommend a small optimization in the clearMarks function.
Here's the change:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="search">
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-balise" id="hide-balise">
    <label for="hide-balise">Balise</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-div" id="hide-div">
    <label for="hide-div">
      <abbr lang="en" title="division">div</abbr>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-div" id="hide-div-with-entities">
    <label for="hide-div-with-entities">
      <abbr lang="en" title="division">&lt;div&gt;</abbr>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-attribut" id="hide-attribut">
    <label for="hide-attribut">Attribut</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-css" id="hide-css">
    <label for="hide-css">
      <abbr lang="en" title="Cascading Style Sheets">mark</abbr>
      (<i lang="en">Cascading Style Sheets</i>)
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide-attribut" id="hide-ancre">
    <label for="hide-ancre">Ancre (<i lang="en">Anchor</i>)</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function addMarks(event) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`>[^<]*${event.currentTarget.value}[^<]*<`, 'gi');
  for (const li of items) {
    li.innerHTML.match(regex)?.forEach((match) => {
      li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replace(
        match,
        match.replaceAll(event.currentTarget.value, `<mark>${event.currentTarget.value}</mark>`),
      );
    });
  }
}

function clearMarks() {
  items.forEach((li) => {
    li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replace(/<\/?mark>/g, '');
  });
}

document.querySelector('input[type=text]').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  clearMarks();
  if (event.currentTarget.value.trim() !== '') {
    addMarks(event);
  }
});
```

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: This answer does not provide any sort of explanation of the problem.